# Python Pandas Dataframe selection using the "in" operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Recently, I've been stuck with a issue that is probably very simple to solve, but after losing hours trying to do it I've decided to ask for help.

So, I have these 2 dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AlleleID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'VariationID':[[1,5,6],[2],[3,7],[4]]
})

df_reviews = pd.DataFrame({
    'VariationID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7],
    'Stars': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0],
    'Source': ['literature', 'clinical', 'inlab', 'inlab', 'literature', 'clinical', 'inlab', 'inlab', 'inlab',\
          'literature', 'literature']
})
```

The intent is for this to be applied to much larger datasets. I create as many columns as I will need to, and I fill them with zeros, adding them to the df dataset. For each row in the df_reviews dataset, I want to use the value of the VariationID column to know which row in the df dataset this one is referring to, then I want to use the other two elements of the row (the number of starts and the source) to know which column in the df I am referring to. Then I just want to increment the value by one.

The goal is just to count how many entries with the different combinations of "Stars" and "Source" exist in the df_reviews dataframe for each different "AlleleID" in df, but each row in df can be connected to multiple different rows in df_reviews, since it has a list of VariationIDs.

I used the following code, and I got the error "KeyError: True"

```
star_values = df_reviews['Stars'].unique()
source_values = df_reviews['Source'].unique()

col_names = []

for e in star_values:
    for f in source_values:
        col_name = 'reviews_stars_%s_source_%s' % (e, f)
        col_names.append(col_name)

    col_name = 'reviews_stars_%s' % (e)
    col_names.append(col_name)

for name in col_names:
    df[name] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype = int)

for row in df_reviews.itertuples(index = False, name = None):
    col_name = 'reviews_stars_%s_source_%s' % (row[0], row[1])
    df.loc[row[2] in df.VariationID,col_name] +=1

print(df)
```

So, what I need, pretty much, is an efficient and fast way (since this will be applied to a dataframe with 500000 rows) to cycle through each of the rows of df_reviews, and incrementing the corresponding position in df by 1.

To do that, and this is the main point of my question, I will need to slice by column based on a label, and by row based on the boolean result of checking if an external value is "in" a row, since the values of that row come as a list (most of the times a list with only one element, but there are exceptions, hence me going with that list format and the "in" method)

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help. I guess it will be a pretty simple question for anyone more familiar with Pandas than me, but it really has me stuck.

This is the desired output:

```
    AlleleID Nome VariationID  reviews_stars_1_source_literature  \
0         1    a   [1, 5, 6]                                    2   
1         2    b         [2]                                    0   
2         3    c      [3, 7]                                    1   
3         4    d         [4]                                    0   

   reviews_stars_1_source_clinical  reviews_stars_1_source_inlab  \
0                                  0                               2   
1                                  0                               1   
2                                  0                               0   
3                                  0                               0   

   reviews_stars_1  reviews_stars_0_source_literature  \
0                   4                                    0   
1                   1                                    0   
2                   1                                    1   
3                   0                                    0   

   reviews_stars_0_source_clinical  reviews_stars_0_source_inlab  \
0                                  1                               0   
1                                  0                               0   
2                                  1                               0   
3                                  0                               0   

    reviews_stars_0  reviews_stars_4_source_literature  \
0                   1                                    0   
1                   0                                    0   
2                   2                                    0   
3                   0                                    0   

   reviews_stars_4_source_clinical  reviews_stars_4_source_inlab  \
0                                  0                               0   
1                                  0                               0   
2                                  0                               0   
3                                  0                               1   

   reviews_stars_4  reviews_stars_3_source_literature  \
0                   0                                    0   
1                   0                                    0   
2                   0                                    0   
3                   1                                    0   

   reviews_stars_3_source_clinical  reviews_stars_3_source_inlab  \
0                                  0                               1   
1                                  0                               0   
2                                  0                               0   
3                                  0                               0   

   reviews_stars_3  
0                   1  
1                   0  
2                   0  
3                   0
```

tl;dr got a "KeyError: true" error while trying to select data from a dataframe by checking if a certain value is "in" each row, with the rows containing lists.

Comment: Could you add the desired output - I'm not quite following your explanation and I think that'd make it clearer for everyone.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the delay. In the end, I want to obtain a single dataframe, with some extra columns that are filled with numbers. The output is too big for this comment I will update the main post.

Comment: Sure... That kind of goes without saying :) please [edit] an example of what the output should be given your example inputs.

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be okay now. I had to translate some terms. It's just a simple question though, it boils down to selecting by a condition that uses the "in" operator

Comment: In your example, `VariationID` is `[[1,5,6],[2],[3,7],[4]]`.  Each integer appears at most once.  Does this property hold for your real data?

Comment: Hey John! Yes, it should hold for my real data. I honestly haven't checked it, but I'm pretty sure that it does. So, for all purposes, imagine it does, and thanks in advance for the help.